# How to use multiple models in django class based generic list view

Tags: django

Here, my code for models.py file,

```
from django.db import models
from config.g_model import TimeStampMixin


# Create your models here.
class Variant(TimeStampMixin):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField()
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Product(TimeStampMixin):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   sku = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField()


class ProductImage(TimeStampMixin):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   file_path = models.URLField()


class ProductVariant(TimeStampMixin):
   variant_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductVariantPrice(TimeStampMixin):
   product_variant_one = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                        related_name='product_variant_one')
   product_variant_two = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                        related_name='product_variant_two')
   product_variant_three = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,
                                          related_name='product_variant_three')
   price = models.FloatField()
   stock = models.FloatField()
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

now here I am using this class based list view,

```
class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    paginate_by = 2
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        products = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(products, self.paginate_by)
        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            products = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
       context['products'] = products
       return context
```

I want to use productimage,product variant and product variant price in my template,I don't know actually how to use multiple models on this view ,if anyoneone can suggesst me it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your models to set related_name as follows

```
class ProductImage(TimeStampMixin):
    # fields as it is
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_images')

class ProductVariant(TimeStampMixin):
    # fields as it is
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_variants')

class ProductVariantPrice(TimeStampMixin):
    # fields as it is
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_variant_prices')
```

In views.py overide get_queryset method

```
class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    # as it is
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('product_images', 'product_variants', 'product_variant_prices')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # as it is
```

prefetch related joins table by product id and fetch data related to that product.